# Relation between Tag and custom table with act-as-taggable gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I want to create relation between table Categories and Tags which  was autogenerated trough  act-as-taggable gem.

I want that Category has one Tag. I tried this:

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :tag
end
```

But it doesnt work. I would emphasize that act-as taggable didnt autogenerate Tag model.

How should I do it properly?

(I am quiet new with Rails)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to manually create Tag model and it will work.